# Node.js & express how to open my rest api on localhost to remote partners?

Tags: node.js

My partners can send http requests to my domain, like this:

```
https://www.example.com/getrequest/
```

As my domain is public.
And I have also enabled CORS.

How to enable such a thing with my localhost during development?

I have tried to visit my Node.js server with my IP address in the url bar in the browser of a different device like this:

```
http://myip:8080
```

But it asks for the WiFi password.
How make my IP available for incoming requests, just similar to my VPS so it will be available to development with partners?

Thanks.

Comment: Will your partners be on the same network as you?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok

Comment: @ChaimFriedman hey, I have tried to install ngrok, but with the program installed on my mac and registered the token they gave and set this to work on port 8080. It works and my node server is available from remote device, like mobile phone.
But its super slow on first load. Is this because its just the free plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your computer to be accessible from the internet you have to enable port forwarding for your router
[Port Forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)

The thing is that your router has a unique IP address yet many devices connect to it so they all share the same IP. The router with port forwarding links a specific device to a specific port so that you can access your computer from `http://ROUTERIPADDRESS:DEVICEPORT` from the outside world.

Comment: Others here recommended about ngrok.
Could you please tell me if manually open ports is faster, more reliable, and more over, secure?

Thanks.

Comment: It is quite fast, you just have to get to the router settings and depending your router there should be a category for port forwarding. There you just enable it and assign a port to the internal ip address for your computer e.g 192.168.0.3 so that your router forwards the port to your computer. As for security, I would do it temporarily not for 'ever'. It could be dangerous depending your computer and firewall configuration.